# Error 403 discord.py with admin privileges?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a command to change a user's nick name.
The bot currently has admin privileges, and the admin role is at the top of the role's list.

However, whenever I run the command, I keep getting this error: 
**Command raised an exception: Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Privilege is too low...**

The code for the cog is

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import discord

class CMDs():
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def change(self, ctx):
        await ctx.message.author.edit(nick="test")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(CMDs(bot))
```

When I googled my problem, the solution was to move the role to the top of the role's list, but that did not work (because I keep getting the error). Does anyone else have any ideas on how I might get this to work?

Comment: If you have given your bot permissions, but it is still giving you errors, you are getting 
H I E R A R C H Y'd
This means that your bot is lower on the role list than the person/role you are trying to edit, or your bot is trying to edit the server owner, which can't happen.

Comment: @mental Yeah, I was trying to edit the server owner. It is a bit of a pain that bot's can't do that, but I will just have to live with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody has or can gain permission to modify the nickname of the guild's owner. This command as written however will work for every other user except the owner.

Comment: That is a bit of a pain, but your solution worked. Thanks!