# I am getting a 403 from discord-lash-py "Task-1" sync_all_commands() but my bot works fine0000

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm getting a 403 error while the bot has administrator. IIRC having administrator should mean that not having permissions is not an issue at all. This doesn't actually break anything but I am wondering why I have a huge error log.

The bot has "bot" and "applications.commands" authorizations.
The only time I am able to get the bug is when using "@slash.subcommand" so I think that is where it is originating from. Like I said before, the slash command works perfectly fine and with the actual bot there is no apparent bug apart from the errors

Below is the code needed to reproduce it. The command in discord will "fail" but that's not super important because its not replying anything. add `ctx.send("stuff")` if you think that's the issue.

**test.py**

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
client = discord.Client(command_prefix='0')
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)

@slash.subcommand(base = 'select', name = 'abbreviations', description = 'Displays all abbreviations', guild_ids=[irrelvant])
async def select_abbreviations(ctx : SlashContext):
    print("select_abbreviations")
    return


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Heres my .env with my obviously hidden token

**.env**

```
DISCORD_TOKEN=token.would.go.here
```

here is the entire log of me starting the bot and typing `/select abbreviations` in discord

```
& c:/path_to_py_stuff/Python/Python39/python test.py
Detected discord.Client! It is highly recommended to use `commands.Bot`. Do not add any `on_socket_response` event.
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<SlashCommand.sync_all_commands() done, defined at C:\path_to_py_stuff\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py:294> exception=Forbidden('403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path_to_py_stuff\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 312, in sync_all_commands
    existing_cmds = await self.req.get_all_commands(guild_id = scope)
  File "C:\path_to_py_stuff\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
select_abbreviations
```

The bot isn't trying to do something impossible like edit a role above itself. It's just trying to make a command which it is succeeding on and giving a random error.

None of these are at all related to this question.

[discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 FORBIDDEN (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822419/discord-errors-forbidden-403-forbidden-error-code-50013-missing-permissions)

[discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions error for setting up roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61128637/discord-errors-forbidden-403-forbidden-error-code-50013-missing-permissions)

[403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access when adding role | discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307903/403-forbidden-error-code-50001-missing-access-when-adding-role-discord-py)

[Error 403 discord.py with admin privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604771/error-403-discord-py-with-admin-privileges)

Comment: This is not a discord.py problem. It is most likely to do with the slash command lib that you are using. I reccomend waiting till an official implementation of slash commands in dpy2

Answer (score 3):

Your Bot is missing permissions to create slash commands in your server.

What you need to do is to go to
[https://discord.com/developers/applications/[your](https://discord.com/developers/applications/%5Byour) app id here]/oauth2

Select "applications.commands" as the scope, then copy the generated URL and open it in a browser. This way you can then allow your application to create (and list) server specific slash commands on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)
 
guild_ids = [] # Put your server ID in this array.
 
@slash.slash(name="test", guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def _test(ctx):
  await ctx.send("test")

slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)
```

This line defines slash

```
guild_ids = []
```

This line sets your guild ID to be used as a slash command

```
@slash.slash(name="test", guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def _test(ctx):
```

These two lines define your command name

```
await ctx.send("test")
```

and this line executes it when it's called